# Centos 7: No WiFi Adapter Found

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ethernet, centos-7

I have a 2 part question:

1. I have dual booted Centos 7 with windows 10. Once Centos 7 setup is finished No WiFi connection is available. In `settings > Wifi` it gives the message:

   > No WiFi adapter found.

   My WiFi adapter is 'Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 BGN WiFi Adapter'.
2. I did some research online and got some responses but cannot try it, since I cannot connect with an Ethernet cable either.

I tried doing it manually but yet again I was unsuccessful.

Update : Till now here is what i tried-

After i saw there was no adapter found, i took out the ethernet cable from the router and plugged it in my laptop, on the top right corner of my screen I can see the icon for lan connection with three dots, and in the "network > wired" tab its displaying connecting but after some time it switched off(maybe because it didnt connected). The i plugged the cable back in router, went to my windows os. from there "ipconfig/all" to know my network details, came back to centos plugged the cable tried to manually connect, but no luck.

In the manual connection i went to ipv4 tab set it from automatic to manual, put my ipv4 address, subnet mask and default gateway ip, in the 'dns row' i entered ip of dns servers(2 of them), and below that there was 'routes row' and i dont know what to enter there so i left it automatic.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: First, thanks for the response i'm in desperate need of help. After i saw there was no adapter found, i took out the ethernet cable from the router and plugged it in my laptop, on the top right corner of my screen I can see the icon for lan connection with three dots, and in the "network > wired" tab its displaying connecting but after some time it switched off(maybe because it didnt connected). The i plugged the cable back in router, went to my windows os. from there "ipconfig/all" to know my network details, came back to centos plugged the cable tried to manually connect, but no luck 1/2.

Comment: 2/2 in the manual connection i went to ipv4 tab set it from automatic to manual, put my ipv4 address, subnet mask and default gateway ip, in the 'dns row' i entered ip of dns servers(2 of them), and below that there was 'routes row' and i dont know what to enter there so i left it automatic.

Comment: Comments are temporary. Please [edit] and update the question with the new information.